# Convergence of series alternating at varying "rates"

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

**Motivation**: We all know the alternating harmonic series

$$\sum (-1)^{n+1} \frac 1n = 1 - \frac 12 + \frac 13  - \frac 14 \cdots$$

is convergent. This is a basic consequence of the alternating series test.

Here, it's quite clear how the "plus" and "minus" signs are behaving. Each term, they switch. Half of the terms, loosely speaking, have $+1$, and the other half have $-1$.

Well, then one may ask, what if we relax this condition, and allow the $-1$ and $+1$ factors to "vary" in the series in an arbitrary manner? Is convergence still a possibility?

**Definitions**:

Let $\alpha:\mathbb{N} \to S \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a real sequence.

Define $\alpha^{-1}[x,n] \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \{k : 1 \leq k \leq n \ \text{and}\ \alpha(k) = x\}$. In other words, $\alpha^{-1}[x,n]$ is the set of naturals at most $n$ which $\alpha$ maps to $x$. (Obviously, $x \in S$.)

Define the *density of $x$ in $\alpha$* as the quantity

$$D(\alpha,x) \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{|\alpha^{-1}[x,n]|}{n} $$

if the limit exists.

**Conjecture:**

> For any $\epsilon \in [0, 1]$, there is always a mapping $s_{\epsilon}:\mathbb{N} \to \{-1,1\}$ such that $$\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{s_{\epsilon}(n)}{n}$$ is convergent and $D(s_{\epsilon}, 1) = \epsilon$.

Note that there is a sort of "symmetry" with the $+1$ and $-1$, which is why we can work with $D(s_{\epsilon}, 1)$ without loss of generality.

**Generalization:**

Consider the above conjecture with $\sum s_{\epsilon}(n)a_n$ where $\{a_n\}$ is such that $\sum a_n$ is conditionally convergent.

Comment: Perhaps this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-EtHF5ND3_s) will inspire you?

Comment: I used a similar argument to prove that $\dfrac{\sin n}{n}$ is convergent. A lot of time after I discovered Fourier series and then I found the actual sum $\dfrac{\pi -1}{2} $. In the sequence $\sin n$ the plus and minus are well behaved. Roughly speaking they are $+,+,+,-,-,-,+,+,+,\ldots$. But in sequence like $\sin n^{11}$ is much more messy. This is the distribution from $\sin 10^6$ to $\sin 10^6 +20$ $\quad -,\; +,\; +,\; +,\; +,\; +,\; +,\; +,\;  -,\; +,\;  -,\;  -,\;  -,\;  -,\; +,\; +,\; +,\; +,\; +,\;  -,\;  -$

Comment: Heuristically, I suspect that it only works if $D(s_\epsilon, 1) = \frac 12$...

Comment: You're right @DominikS ; Intuitively $D(s_{\epsilon}, 1) = \frac 12$ is the only one that works, now that I think about it. The negatives and positives need to cancel each other out, in some sense. But how to prove it...

Comment: If $a_n \downarrow 0$ monotonically, then a necessary condition for convergence is $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\sum_{k=1}^n s(k)\right) a_n$ where $s(n)$ is any sequence in $\{-1,+1\}$.  See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2212686/148510)

Comment: See Q # 2377994 which  was posted yesterday.